# ScrollBar is not showing in WPF ListView which is inside nested User and Content Controls

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

Please help me in this issue of scroll bar visibility in WPF listview.
I have a listview inside a Content Control.
This Content Control is inside a User Control.
This User Control is inside a TabItem.

The listview has around 12 columns to display, which exceeds the window width.
I tried so many ways to show the horizontal scroll bar in the listview.

Below shown is the XAML of the Outer UserControl [width is not set for this outer usrCrtl]

```
       <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
               <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
               <RowDefinition Height="*" />   // Here I have a custom content control
               <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <MyCustomContentControl Grid.Row=1  VerticalAlignment="Stretch"......>
               <TabControl>
                   <TabItem Header="One" Name="Tab1">
                        <my:usrAControl />   // I have listview inside this userctrl                       
                    </TabItem>
               </TabControl>
               <TabControl Header="Two" Name="Tab2" />
            </MyCustomContentControl>
       </Grid>
```

Now below is the usrAControl XAML details

```
       <UserControl x:Class="MyProject.MyModule.usrAControl"
            MinWidth="640">
          // Again inside another custom user control as its child.
             <usrBControl>
                  <Grid>
                     <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                         <RowDefinition Height="30" /> // here another headers
                         <RowDefinition Height="*" />  // here my listview placed
                     </Grid.RowDefinitions>  

                     <ListView ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Grid.Row="1"
                               Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=Width}">

                      // Around 12 columns which exceeds window width

                     </ListView>  
                  </Grid>
             </usrBControl>             
       </usrAControl>
```

I tried with lot of combination.
I initially put a scrollviewer control inside the tabitem and placed usrAControl inside it.
But it did not work.

But I want the listview should show its both scroll bars. Is any way to do it.?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing more code, my guess would be that the `MinSize="640"` is your problem: the `ListView` gets enough space from its container so it doesn't show the scroll, but the container gets clipped.

And you should get rid of the `ListView` `Width` binding, it's completely redundant.

Comment: Hi Eli Arbel, I tried again by removing MinWidth and ListView width binding, still no use. Any other way ???

Comment: Hi Eli, I fixed it by putting a scrollviewer as the parent to the listview. So now the both scroll bars are visible. Thanks for your time, suggestions and help